# Sort multidimentional array in php using key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort the below array using php. The array should sort by value of services [0][1]...

```
Array
(
[Services] => Array
    (
        [0] => Travel & Hotels  ~72
        [1] => Automotive~119
        [3] => Professional Services~71
        [4] => Home Services~70
        [6] => IT Services & Computer Repair~83
        [8] => Health and Medical~69
    )

[Restaurants] => Array
    (
        [0] => American / Eclectic~2
        [1] => Cafe~11
        [2] => Desserts & Bakery~111
    )

[Shopping] => Array
    (
        [0] => Office Equipment~103
        [3] => Department Stores~91
        [15] => Cosmetics & Beauty Supply~90
        [16] => Musical Instruments & Teachers~102
        [17] => Food~87
    )

[Entertainment] => Array
    (
        [0] => Bars/Pubs~48
    )

[Travel] => Array
    (
        [0] => Hotels~129
    )
)
```

Comment: i am new to this can you please help me i tried usort but its not working

Comment: If you tried, then, please, show your approach

Comment: i am storing this array in $temp. so I tried like usort($temp); i am not have any idea on this please help me

Comment: Probably similar question is answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean by "The array should sort by value of services [0][1]…"

Comment: @PatrickQ the sorting should done inside service,restaurants,shopping and etc that is inside service automotive,home service and etc should be sorted

Comment: Yes, but what is your definition of sorting? Alphabetic? A-Z? Z-A? Do you want to maintain indexes?

Comment: @PatrickQ Alphabetic A-Z and array format should remain same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as doing this (assuming that `$attractionArray` is the outer array given above):

```
foreach($attractionsArray as $key => $innerArray)
{
    sort($innerArray, SORT_STRING);
    $attractionArray[$key] = $innerArray;
}
```

[See it in action here](http://3v4l.org/3U5G2)